# Fetch value from Redmine Custom Custom field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, redmine-api

I have created custom field in redmine wher we type the client phone number manually.Also written a ruby code in redmine custom workflow to send sms to client when ticket id is raised.In the code I can type phone number but i actually want to fetch that phone number which we type before creating the new issue..So how do i fetch the value of phone number from the custom field and link it to the code?
Please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

```
IssueCustomField.where("field = 8 AND value like '+31%'")
```

Replace the field number with the field number of your custom field and if you want to filter on some type of phone number, use the above like format