# How to get the value enetered in custom field in custom workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, redmine-api

I'm new to redmine. I want to get the value from one custom field and set it to other. So how can I get the value of custom field in custom workflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch value from Redmine Custom Custom field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042603/fetch-value-from-redmine-custom-custom-field)

Comment: yeahh its same but answer is not given.Please tel me how to solve this